# Spring Boot 3 - missing dispatcherServletRegistration bean in actuator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-3

When i start my spring boot 3.2.0 application and call the health endpoint i get the error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find servlet [dispatcherServletRegistration] in the servlet context
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:172)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry$DispatcherServletDelegatingRequestMatcher.matcher(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java:529)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.check(RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.check(RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.authorization.ObservationAuthorizationManager.check(ObservationAuthorizationManager.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:95)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:181)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:224)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1586)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler$MappedServlet.handle(ServletHandler.java:1547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletChannel.dispatch(ServletChannel.java:838)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletChannel.handle(ServletChannel.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler$Wrapper.handle(Handler.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.EventsHandler.handle(EventsHandler.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpChannelState$HandlerInvoker.run(HttpChannelState.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.internal.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
```

When i add a DispatcherServletRegistrationBean in my Application like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistrationBean() {
        return new DispatcherServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet(), "/");
    }

    private DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        return new DispatcherServlet(context);
    }
}
```

The application fails to start and i get the following error:

```
Parameter 0 of method errorPageCustomizer in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - dispatcherServletRegistrationBean: defined by method 'dispatcherServletRegistrationBean' in com.core.SpringApplication
    - dispatcherServletRegistration: defined by method 'dispatcherServletRegistration' in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration.class]
```

Im using an actuator configuration that works for 4 other microservices, so its going to be hard to reproduce the problem. Does anyone have an idea how this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. In my case I had set a different port for the actuator. When I removed it and used the same port as the application, issue got resolved.

Root Cause:
I had set below property

`management.endpoint.port=8081`

This caused a new servlet to be initialized

`Initializing Servelet 'dispatcherServletRegistration'`

However this servelet is not registerd in the Application context. In spring security 6.2.1 they have a condition for matching the requestMatcher with the servletname before processing the permitAll functionality. As the new dispatcherServletRegistration is not added to the application context, it fails there and causes this issue. I am not sure why actuator is initializing a new servlet and not using the existing dispatcherServlet.

Note: I was not able to solve how to set actuator on a different port and have this work but after several hours of debugging, I leave that to others.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, with my actuator on an other port.
One solution can be to use another SecurityFilterChain for your actuators :

1st filterChain (The one you already have) :

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .securityMatcher(new NegatedRequestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()))
            ...
            .authorizeHttpRequests(...).build()
}
```

The securityMatcher + NegatedRequestMatcher will make this fitlerChain ignored what you pass in arguments: Here it's EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint() which correspond to any Actuator you may have. It can be EndpointRequest.to("actuatorName") or for a path : new AntPathRequestMatcher("/path/**")

Then the second SecurityFilterChain which permitAll:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain actuatorFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests.anyRequest().permitAll());
    return http.build();     
}
```

source : [Actuator endpoints returning 500 error after upgrade to spring boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77710370/actuator-endpoints-returning-500-error-after-upgrade-to-spring-boot-3)

EDIT :

If the objective is to authorise everything for Actuators or paths with another port, you can do it with only one filterChain :
From my answer, forget the actuatorFilterChain() and remove the .securityMatcher(...) from filterChain() and add a WebSecurityCustomizer Bean like that :

```
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return web -> web.ignoring()
            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint());
            //.requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("actuatorName")); 
            //.requestMatchers("/path/**");
        }
```

It'll ignore security for what you specify in the requestMatcher whitout the 500 Exception caused by RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager